# AssertWasCalled on method in SystemUnderTest

Tags: c#-4.0, tdd, rhino-mocks

I'm getting into TDD; using nUnit and RhinoMocks 3.5.

I'm trying to figure out how to AssertWasCalled on a method in the SystemUnderTest (SUT). My understanding is that you can't mock the system under test. In fact, my current test results in an exception because the I'm using the AssertWasCalled on the SUT.

OrdersPresenter:

```
public void OnViewLoad_GetOrders()
{
    var orders = GetOrders();
    View.Model.Orders = orders;
}

public List<Orders> GetOrders()
{
    return _ordersRepository.GetAll();
}
```

OrdersPresenterTest:

```
_ordersPresenter = new OrdersPresenter(_view, _ordersRepository);

[Test]
public void OnViewLoad_GetOrders_Should_Call_GetOrders()
{
    _view.Raise(v => v.LoadOrders += _ordersPresenter.OnViewLoad_GetOrders, view, new EventArgs);
    _ordersPresenter.AssertWasCalled(d => d.GetOrders); // Getting non-mock exception here
}
```

How do I Assert GetOrders was called in the SUT? I haven't been able to figure it out in the docs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I understand the GetOrders method in the SUT should be private. I went back thru Roy Osherove's *Art of Unit Testing* to see how to test private methods. Roy says making a method public (to test against) is not necessarily a bad thing, so I will keep it public.

So I've written a test for GetOrders and I assert the return value *ShouldBe* a list of orders. That said, I believe I need to restructure my test for OnViewLoad_GetOrders by stubbing the value I get from GetOrders and asserting the results of my actions on that object.

Can someone confirm and explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `AssertWasCalled()` on not-mocked objects. Just abstract class `OrdersPresenter` by an interface (use Extract Interface refactoring technique) and then

```
var ordersPresenter = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IOrderRepository>();

view.Raise(...);
_ordersPresenter.AssertWasCalled(d => d.GetOrders);
```

BTW,

for me it is not clear why RhinoMocks not used generic parameter constraint for AssertWasCalled

```
public static void AssertWasCalled<T>(this T mock, Action<T> action, 
    Action<IMethodOptions<object>> setupConstraints)
```

Basically `T` is not limited, but I believe it would be better limit it to somethign like `IMockMarkerInterface`